# Intel TBB parallel loop thread id

Tags: c++, multithreading, intel, tbb, parallel.for

How do I determine thread id in a TBB parallel loop body?

Essentially what I need is per-thread copies of an object so I thought I'd have those in array indexed by thread id.

I'm looking for the portable TBB way of doing this, not OS native services.

Comment: You can create these objects and explicitly pass them to the threads, no need for a lookup by TID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search term you are looking for is "thread-local storage". Since you are already using TBB, you should probably just use the facilities it provides:

https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/thread_local_storage.htm

Comment: great, thanks! enumerable_thread_specific is what I wanted

btw tbb::this_tbb_thread::get_id() is what I'd have used if that TLS container wasn't available